Horizontal Alignment of Columns in a tabularx environment
How could I center the columns in the following table using tabularx based on numbers and not all symbols in a cell. Right now it is centered taking into account the stars, but I would like to center based on numbers only.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Example table}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lYYY} \hline \hline
& & & \\
& (1) & (2) & (3) \\
& & & \\
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Example Panel} \\ \cline{2-4}
Coefficient             &  -10     &   -211** &   260*** \\
Standard Error          & (414)    &   (110)  &   (90)   \\
Observations            &  123,370 &  32,268  &  73,102  \\
Variation               &  0.08    &  0.08    &  0.06    \\
Statistics              &  13,115  &  12,826  & 14,031   \\
& & & \\
\hline \hline
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont
\item
\textit{Notes:}
Some table notes
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Here you are with tabular* rather than tabularx.
I gauged by eye that the width of *** is about a quad. The asterisks are typeset in a zero width box.
A dirty trick is used to get the minus sign right (the entries are typeset as math) and the comma to be an ordinary math symbol.
Note also the use of caption so proper spacing is applied between caption and table; the default of article is to place captions below tables.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,caption}

\newcommand{\st}[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{#1}}
\newcommand{\decimalcomma}{\mathcode`,=\inteval{\mathcode`,-"6000}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering

\caption{Example table}

\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{3}{>{$\decimalcomma}c<{$}}
  @{\quad}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Example Panel} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
& (1) & (2) & (3) \\
\midrule
Coefficient             &  -10     &   -211\st{**} &   260\st{***} \\
Standard Error          & (414)    &   (110)       &   (90)   \\
Observations            &  123,370 &  32,268       &  73,102  \\
Variation               &  0.08    &  0.08         &  0.06    \\
Statistics              &  13,115  &  12,826       &  14,031   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item \textit{Notes:} Some table notes
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}

I removed double rules and empty rows. I also switched the first two lines, because “Example Panel” is at a higher level than (1), (2) and (3).

If you also want that the minus sign doesn't participate to the centering and to just input * rather than \st{*}, you can. But don't blame me if this won't always work.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,caption}

\newcommand{\st}[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{#1}}
\newcommand{\decimalcomma}{\mathcode`,=\inteval{\mathcode`,-"6000}}
\newcommand{\zerowidthminus}{%
  \mathchardef\standardminus=\mathcode`-
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`-\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\llap{$\standardminus$}}%
  \mathcode`-="8000
}
\newcommand{\noteasterisk}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`*\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\zwast
  \mathcode`*="8000
}
\newcommand{\zwast}{\hbox to 0pt\bgroup*\checkast}
\newcommand{\checkast}[1]{*\futurelet\next\checkastaux}
\newcommand{\checkastaux}{%
  \ifx\next*%
    \expandafter\checkast
  \else
    \expandafter\hss\expandafter\egroup
  \fi
}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{$\decimalcomma\zerowidthminus\noteasterisk}c<{$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering

\caption{Example table}

\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{3}{N}
  @{\quad}
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c@{\quad}}{Example Panel} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
& (1) & (2) & (3) \\
\midrule
Coefficient             &  -10     &   -211** &   260***\\
Standard Error          & (414)    &   (110)       &   (90)   \\
Observations            &  123,370 &  32,268       &  73,102  \\
Variation               &  0.08    &  0.08         &  0.06    \\
Statistics              &  13,115  &  12,826       &  14,031   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item \textit{Notes:} Some table notes
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}


The only “nonautomatic” part is gauging the number of asterisks and their position in the last column, so they don't stick out of the table. Without @{\quad} you'd get


column 1 and 2 are not centered though? Is it possible to center any column just based on numbers automatically? If I do it manually I have to change ti every time I have a new combination of numbers, stars, and minus sign.

@TrevorAndrew I added a different method.

If you want to stick with the tabularx setup, one way to achieve your formatting objective would be to use the \rlap macro -- or its math-mode cousin, \mathrlap (provided by the mathtools package) -- to encase ** and ***, respectively.
Since you make only highly rudimentary use of the capabilities of the threeparttable machinery (e.g., no \tnote directives), I'd drop the threeparttable environment entirely. And I'd replace the \hline\hline directives and multiple blank lines with \toprule, \cmidrule, and \bottomrule instructions, which are macros provided by the booktabs package. Finally, no need for \footnotesize in the tabularx material.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}  % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of 'X'
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{$}Y<{$}} % automatic math mode

\usepackage{booktabs}  % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathrlap' macro
\usepackage{icomma}    % no special treatment of ',' in math mode

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Example table}

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l ZZZ @{}}
\toprule
& (1) & (2) & (3) \\[1ex]
& \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Example Panel} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
Coefficient    &  -10   & -211\mathrlap{^{**}} & 260\mathrlap{^{***}} \\
Standard Error & (414)    &   (110)  &   (90)   \\
Observations   &  123,370 &  32,268  &  73,102  \\
Variation      &  0.08    &  0.08    &  0.06    \\
Statistics     &  13,115  &  12,826  & 14,031   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip\small
\textit{Notes:} Some stuff \dots 
\end{table}

\end{document}


I believe that column 1 and 2 are not centered? Is it because of the minus sign?

@TrevorAndrew - To my taste, the numbers in columns 1 and 2 do look centered, as I believe that the - symbols are essential parts of the respective numbers in row 1. Conversely, if you wanted to visually downgrade the - symbols, you could write \mathllap{-}10 and \mathllap{-}211\mathrlap{^{**}}, resp.
